# Dual blockchain

Tags: dapps, ethereumj, consensus, hyperledger-fabric

Could anybody please help me to understand how dual blockchains work? There are many Dapps which are built on dual blockchains, especially using the combination of Ethereum and Hyperledger.

But I am unable to understand how to integrate the two? And how consensus would work in such scenarios?

P.s- i am a newbie in blockchain world. All the suggestions/helps/comments are welcome. Thanks! :)

Comment: good question, why would we need Hyperledger at all? Looks like some vaporware product created just because everybody works on blockchain technology, but without any real need behind

Comment: Hyperledger is a consortium of blockchain platforms under the Linux Foundation.  The above discusses Hyperledger Fabric, from IBM. There is also Hyperledger Sawtooth, which supports Ethereum Dapps through Seth (Sawtooth Ethereum VM, implemented on Sawtooth with Hyperledger Burrow).

Answer (score 1):

Combining Blockchains is not really possible right now, it is safe to say it's something "Futuristic" right now. The ethereum network is a very closed system in which nodes communicate and agree with each other based on an algorithm called the consensus algorithm.

The Consensus algorithm **doesn't allow** the **interaction** **between the nodes and any other system outside the network**. The only way we can interact with the network is via the nodes interface.

So the "Dual Blockchain" idea is probably just a **fault tolerance** measure taken by Dapps to ensure they stay in business even if one blockchain they are connected to fails for some reason (which is very not probable).

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly combine the two. You can't really directly combine almost anything with Ethereum blockchain as it's incompatible with all other things. You definitely can't interfere with the consensus algorithms in Ethereum with external systems directly.

All communications have to go through nodes. Nodes are the gateway to "other" technologies and whatnot. So, in order to create something which uses both Hyperledger and Ethereum, there needs to be at least a node which handles the communication - most likely a full backend system. So, it doesn't really make a difference whether the other system is something like a distributed ledger or a regular database.